# I need to create a pandas dataframe that shows which topics the tweets are represented by

Tags: python, nltk, lda, topic-modeling

Determining topics by using Lateral Dirichlet Allocation

```
tokenized = tweets['initial']
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tokenized)
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=1, no_above=0.8)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(tokens) for tokens in tokenized]
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics = 5, id2word=dictionary, passes=15)
ldamodel.save('mOdel.gensim')
topics = ldamodel.print_topics(num_words=10)
for topic in topics:
    print(topic)
```

[You can see output of this block from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqUVo.jpg)

Dataframe that shows which topic represents tweets [dataframe that should do that but not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idCYa.jpg)

```
def dominant_topic(ldamodel,corpus,content):
    #Function to find the dominant topic in each query
    sent_topics_df = pd.DataFrame()
    # Get main topic in each query
    for i, row in enumerate(ldamodel[corpus]):
        row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
    # Get the Dominant topic, Perc Contribution and Keywords for each query
    for j, (topic_num, prop_topic) in enumerate(row):
        if j == 0:  # =&gt; dominant topic
            wp = ldamodel.show_topic(topic_num,topn=20)
            topic_keywords = ", ".join([word for word, prop in wp])
            sent_topics_df = sent_topics_df.append(pd.Series([int(topic_num), round(prop_topic,4), topic_keywords]), ignore_index=True)
        else:
            break
        sent_topics_df.columns = ['Dominant_Topic', 'Perc_Contribution', 'Topic_Keywords']
        contents = pd.Series(content)#noisy data
        sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, contents], axis=1)
    return(sent_topics_df)

df_dominant_topic = dominant_topic(ldamodel=ldamodel, corpus=corpus, content=tweets['initial'])
df_dominant_topic.head(5)
```

I can see just first one. This is the problem.

Comment: use `print()` in many places to display values in variables and which part of code is executed - it helps you see if code works as you expected. It is called `"print debuging"`. OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: I expect that problem is `else: break` which exits `for`-loop after first item - so it can't add other items. I don't know what you expceted with this `break`

Comment: I see also other possible problem. In first `for`-loop you assign to varable `row = ` so you can keep only one result and later you may work only with this one result. If you want to work with many items then you should create empty list before `for`-loop and inside `for`-loop you should append items to this list.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. Problem caused by incorrect use of block and solved.

Comment: @yamukkep can you share your solution?